# Storage Strangely Full

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, internal-storage

My dad has a Moto G2, and I had similar problems with my Moto G2 and my Samsung Galaxy Y.

His storage is almost full - at 4.53 GB/5.51 GB. The strange stuff comes when we go to the storage section in settings, and it gives us a breakdown of what is taking up space.

Apps        1.99  GB

Images      132   MB

Other       20.38 MB

Cached Data 8.38  MB

(Nothing on anything else)

If I am correct - that's only ~2.15GB! Where is the other ~2.38GB?
And how do we get it back?

Moto G2 on Android 6.0 - System Updates says "Your device's software is up to date."

Answer (score 2):

It is used as system storage ie the space on which your OS and system apps are installed. If you have expandable storage, you may be able to install user apps on an external sd card.

Comment: That's what I thought, but the 5.51GB is Internal Storage separate from the OS. The total storage on the phone is 8GB and the OS is 2.49GB leaving 5.51GB for the apps and other stuff.

Comment: Hmm strange. Here's what you should do: install a File Manager app like ES Explorer. It should show you what is causing the anomaly.